# Get category name from product detail page

Tags: product, category

I have an URL from which I would like to get the categories. I have this: /hats/trucker-hats/hat1.html/ which is a product detail page.

I need to retrieve the categories, which are "hats" and "trucker-hats". I tried using `$product->getCategoryIds()` and looked through the IDs, the categories are there, but never at the same index, is there a way to retrieve these?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "never at the same index" ?

Comment: When I look at the array of category ids from page to page, I find the same ids, but they don't always have the same index in the array

Answer (score 1):

You can get categories from the breadcrumbs

```
$title = array();
$path  = Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath();
foreach ($path as $breadcrumb) {
    $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a consistent ordering you can use `asort()`.